# EF Core 1.1 Many To Many Relation (ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to create a model with a many-to-many relation:

- A Company can have 0 or more Users
- A Company can have 0 or more Roles
- The many to many relation is between Users and Roles

Every time i try to create the database (update-database) I have the message:

**Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_UsersRoles_Users_UserId' on table 'UsersRoles' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.**

and I don't understand what cycles it refers to. I mean, if I deleted a user it has to delete the entity inside UsersRoles and nothing more. The same if I delete a Role.

If my model has only Users and Roles, **without the Company table**, the database is created.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server = (localdb)\\mssqllocaldb; Database = ConsoleApp1; Trusted_Connection = True; MultipleActiveResultSets = true");

        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>()
            .ToTable("UsersRoles")
            .HasKey(t => new { t.UserId, t.RoleId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.User)
            .WithMany(p => p.UsersRoles)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.UserId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Role)
            .WithMany(t => t.UsersRoles)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.RoleId);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserRole> UsersRoles { get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserRole> UsersRoles { get; set; }
}

public class UserRole
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The cycle is when you delete a company. It has to cascade delete the related users **and** roles, which in turn has to delete the `UserRole` records. Hence one and the same `UserRole`  can be deleted either thru `User` or `Role`. Since SqlServer database does not support that, EF (Core) also does not support it (although other RDBMS like Oracle have no issues with such relationships).

Comment: Unserstood. So one solution is to disable cascade deleting on Companies inside OnModelCreating and delete the Users and Roles manually when a Company is deleted. `modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().
                HasMany(h => h.Users).
                WithOne(w => w.Company)
                .OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().
                HasMany(h => h.Roles).
                WithOne(w => w.Company)
                .OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.Restrict);`

Comment: Correct. Although it should be enough to turn the cascade delete off for one of the entities causing cycle. For instance, `Company` -> `Users` and just delete related `Users` before deleting company.

Comment: @Manfrons, this post and comments helped me understand the problem with my dbcontext configuration. I suggest that you summarize information from comments and post a self-answer (ping me if you do it and I will +1 an answer as well as the question)